# Got this at a sale. What set is it for? Lots of greys with 4 legs

Tags: set-identification, star-wars

Got this at a sale.  What set is it for?
Some one knows.

[image: Lots of greys with 4 legs]

Answer (score 4):

This is from

[7869: Battle for Geonosis](https://brickset.com/sets/7869-1/Battle-for-Geonosis)
[image]

Keypart

- [Dark Bluish Gray Brick, Round Corner 6 x 6 x 2](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=87559&colorID=85&in=A)